# MYSQL: sorting by 2 columns that have similar data

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have 2 columns, called GenreID, and CustomGenre (referring to the genre of a book). GenreID is an integer which refers to genres listed in a different table, in a colume called GenreName. CustomGenre allows the user to enter their own text for this row if they don't like any of the pre-defined options, or if they want to add more information, like a subgenre.

What I'd like to be able to do, is sort these alphabetically simultaneously, with the preference for GenreName. So, if the row has a GenreID, then it gets sorted by GenreName. If the row doesn't have a GenreID (or it's zero) then CustomGenre gets treated as if it were GenreName, so that I end up with a list where if I display "GenreName, CustomGenre" it's actually in alphabetical order, even if the row did not refer to any GenreName.

Just in case that's not clear, here's a little example:

```
Genre:
GenreID  GenreName
1        Sci-Fi
2        Fantasy
```

```
Books:
Book           GenreID   CustomGenre
Example        1          Futurism
A Book         2 
Another Book!             Horror
```

And I'd like those to get sorted like this, where the 2nd column is alphebetized:

```
Results:
Book            GenreName + CustomGenre
A Book            Fantasy
Another Book!     Horror
Example           Sci-fi, Futurism
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Book, 
   CONCAT(IFNULL(GenreName,""), IF(GenreName IS NOT NULL, ", ", ""), IF(CustomGenre = "", "", CustomGenre)) As BookGenre
FROM Books LEFT OUTER JOIN Genre
ON Books.GenreID = Genre.GenreID
ORDER BY BookGenre
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebe73/23

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    b.Book,
    CONCAT( b.CustomGenre, g.GenreName) as the_genre
FROM 
    Books b
LEFT JOIN Genre g
    ON b.GenreID = g.GenreID
ORDER BY
    the_genre
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way

```sql
SELECT book, TRIM(BOTH ', ' FROM 
                  CONCAT(COALESCE(g.genrename, ''), ', ',
                         COALESCE(b.customgenre, ''))) genre
  FROM book b LEFT JOIN genre g
    ON b.genreid = g.genreid
 ORDER BY COALESCE(g.genrename, b.customgenre)
```

Output:

```
|          BOOK |            GENRE |
|---------------|------------------|
|        A Book |          Fantasy |
| Another Book! |           Horror |
|       Example | Sci-Fi, Futurism |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44717/6)** demo